# Determining execution time of a thread and IO accesses by different threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix

I want to determine execution time of a thread in a multi-threaded program, and I also want to know about IO accesses made by each thread.

Is there any command/tool which can do this for C programs?

Answer (score 0):

For determining the execution you could try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (specifically the callgrind module).  There is also a neat visualization tool for the output called [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

For monitoring IO access you could use [strace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace).