# Is it possible to know how much CPU usage the current thread is getting?

Tags: linux, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a task scheduler for offloaded tasks in a game engine, and I want it to tune itself based on a few heuristics.
Is it possible to know for how long the current thread has been executed between two points in time? I want to time how long tasks take to execute, and I would like that time to exclude thread switching for multiple reasons (its a more accurate measurement, plus it would be useful to know how much my threads are being switched out).
I would like a solution for linux but a windows solution would also be appreciated

Comment: this answer could help:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689406/determining-execution-time-of-a-thread-and-io-accesses-by-different-threads/1691192#1691192

Comment: That is useful, thanks, although I want my program to be able to do it itself in code, but I suppose I could have a third process that gets the output of valgrind and communicates it back to the game engine :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at /proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/stat

Format is similar to /proc/[pid]/stat and explained here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: That is fantastic! More information than I could ever want :)

Answer (score 1):

Example code from [pthread_getcpuclockid() man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html) indicates that you could use [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &ts)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html indicates that this won't work if the computer has multiple cores, is there a way around this?

Comment: if `*_getcpuclockid()` return `ENOENT` then you could try to set CPU affinity `pthread_setaffinity_np()`, `sched_setaffinity()`.